# I cant install with npm anymore

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

Npm was working just fine, then today I tried to install @ngui/tab using the following command :

```
npm install @ngui/tab --save
```

it gave me the following error :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\alpha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'core-js' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.4
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 verbose npm-session 08b82689ec3193f8
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for core-js@file:node_modules\core-js ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open 'D:\Crescendo veille\app2\node_modules\core-js\package.json'
8 verbose stack Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open 'D:\...\node_modules\core-js\package.json'
8 verbose stack     at Error (native)
9 verbose cwd D:\Crescendo veille\app2
10 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
11 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\alpha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "core-js"
12 verbose node v6.11.0
13 verbose npm  v5.0.4
14 error path D:\...\node_modules\core-js\package.json
15 error code ELOOP
16 error errno -4067
17 error syscall open
18 error ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open 'D:\...\node_modules\core-js\package.json'
19 verbose exit [ -4067, true ]
```

Then whenever I try to install another plugin, it gives the same exact error

Comment: Can you try npm init first then your command

Comment: did you try to delete node_modules and try to npm install...?

Comment: no I didnt try to delete it, coz I have a lot of plugins and it is gonna take forever to download all of em @n00dl3, do you suggest that I do that ?

Comment: @Codeminer I 'll try it now !

Comment: something has messed up your node_moduels folder, so deleting it might fix the problem...

Comment: @Codeminer still same problem

Comment: @n00dl3 I'll try to delete it now

Comment: @Codeminer not it is not working, yes it exists

Comment: @n00dl3 I deleted the node_modules and ran the "npm install " command, it installed the plugins, but when I try to : npm install @ngui/tab --save   it gives the same problem

Comment: is it a problem with core-js ?

Comment: I solved the problem, I found that "node_modules/core.js" folder was corrupted , I deleted it and replaced it with a "core.js" folder (that I saved as a backup if things goes wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem, I found that "node_modules/core.js" folder was corrupted , I deleted it and replaced it with a "core.js" folder (that I saved as a backup if things goes wrong)

Comment: This solution helped me figure out my issue. I made the mistake of doing an "npm install" while I was inside the node_modules directory. Also, make sure to check the package.js in case you did a --save on the failed install..

Answer (score 2):

When I encountered this issue it was because I accidentally ran `npm install` while in the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: I was doing the same mistake. Thank you for your answer.