# Not able to install Angular CLI in windows system using latest npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to install Angular CLI in my Windows 7 system command prompt using npm.

Getting the error as:

> ```
> D:\Users\uname>npm install -g @angular/cli
> npm ERR! code ELOOP
> npm ERR! syscall stat
> npm ERR! path \\mysystempath\ViewData\
> npm ERR! errno -62
> npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat '\\mysystempath\ViewData\'
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     \\mysystempath\ViewData\Users\uname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-7T10_14_28_716Z-debug.log
> ```

- node version: v10.18.1
- npm version: 6.13.4

Please help me.

Comment: Try this one and let us know [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587430/i-cant-install-with-npm-anymore)

Comment: @SameerKhan, i don't see any file like core.js in the node_modules folder as mentioned in the above Link.

Answer (score 0):

You get all kinds of weird messgages if node/ npm versions are not compatible.
Make sure you are using the correct version of node/ npm

eg:

PS C:\Windows\system32> npm -v

6.4.1

PS C:\Windows\system32> node -v

v10.13.0

Answer (score -1):

Delete the node modules and update the angular cli version and do the following:

```
npm install
ng serve
```